# Click handler not getting invoked after html write

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this code:

```
 document.getElementById('form1').innerHTML = user_selections.stockyard_html[sel];

 alert('click handler registered');
 $("#" + register_btn_id).click(function (event){
alert("Clicked");
});
```

After html overwrite of form html which was saved yesterday, there is a register button whose click I'm not able to catch. What could be the reason?

Comment: You need to show the HTML that goes with this.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)

Comment: @Andreas sure I'll give

Comment: You might want to use event delegation if you are playing a lot with the DOM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside document ready:

```
$(function() {
   $("#" + register_btn_id).on('click', function(e) {
       alert('clicked')
   )}
})
```